# Does PayPal Adaptive Payment method support in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I would like to integrate **Paypal's Adaptive payment method** for **Saudi Arabia** region.
I have searched this on google as well as i have gone through the paypal documentation.
I found that Express checkout is supported. But i did not find Adaptive method.

In my web application, Platform owner and all the sellers are based in Saudi Arabia?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PayPal adaptive payment is available in the country where it accepts PayPal. However, adaptive payment is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.

I would advise you submit the adaptive payment application from the following url:-
https://www.paypal-apps.com/developers/app-management

The PayPal vetting team will get back to you to approve/denied the request.

Please note that, for parallel payment, you can use express checkout to integrate parallel payment. More details on:-
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/

Regards,
Giovani